# ERROR 1064 (42000) creating table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a new table in the database.

```
mysql> create table 'lps_inventory' (eartag int(11) not null,
    -> bulk tinyint(4),
    -> hpt int(11),
    -> idbox varchar(30),
    -> location char(10),
    -> comnt varchar(40));
```

I got this error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'creat table 'lps_inventory' (eartag int(11) not null,
>       bulk tinyint(4),
>       hpt int(1' at line 1

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
quote should be `, not ', or do it without quote.
```

Comment: This is embarrassing. I use create, still same error.

Comment: lps_inventory should not be in quotes

Comment: you don't need quotes

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
create table lps_inventory (eartag int(11) not null,
    bulk tinyint(4),
     hpt int(11),
     idbox varchar(30),
     location char(10),
     comnt varchar(40));
```